# App packaged by electron-forge not loading localhost

Tags: electron, localhost, electron-forge

My `electron` `main.js` code:

```js
function createWindow () {
    const { screen } = require('electron');

    const primaryDisplay    = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
    const { width, height } = primaryDisplay.workAreaSize;

    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width,
        height,

        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
        },
    });
    
    return mainWindow;
}

function createServerProcess () {
    serverProcess = fork(__dirname + '/index.js');
}

app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    createServerProcess();
    let mainWindow = createWindow();
    
    let workspaceId = await localStorage.getItem('workspaceId');
    if (!workspaceId) {
        workspaceId = 'abc';
    }
    let url = `http://${workspaceId}.localhost:8443`;

    setTimeout(() => {
        mainWindow.loadURL(url);
    }, 3000);
});
```

I am using `electron-forge` to build my electron app, using `electron-forge start` to start local app works fine. But when starting the app generated by `electron-forge make` command, it shows below error:

[image]

I have already set `webSecurity` to `false`, for turning off cross origin restriction. Just don't know why while local app works fine but generated app is not working. I am confused. I am new to `Electron`.

Comment: I have the same issue :/